# Colour isolation

Tags: colors, gimp, levels

I'm fairly new to GIMP

I have some black-and-white images in RGB mode. I want to highlight some areas in plain Red (ie, zero Blue+Green), some in plain Blue (ie, zero Red+Green), and the rest in plain Green (ie, zero Red+Blue)

I will be selecting several areas using Paths, though a simple rectangle would be fine for now

The final image will be Green, with 2+ selections of Red, and 2+ selections of Blue

I have experimented with multiple layers & multiple images, but I always get problems with the selection areas

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the "problems"? How do you create the selections? If you are ttrhing to map levels of gray to Red/Green/Blue, see the [Gradient Map](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-gradmap.html) or the [Palette Map](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-palettemap.html) filters.

Comment: xenoid - Hard to answer, I've tried several approaches. I think I need 3 layers - background just the Green component, next layer 2 selections with just the Blue component & rest transparent, top layer 2 selections with just Red component & rest transparent. Struggling to set up multiple selections for different layers. Struggling also to apply colours to just 1 layer. Maybe overall approach is wrong ?

Comment: Possible, but since we don't know [what you want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) it is hard to make suggestions.

Comment: xenoid - I have some b/w astronomical images. I want to isolate certain areas "R" of the image, and certain other areas "B" of the image without changing the intensities. Whatever's left I label "G". I will then post-process the resulting single RGB image with some software - each pixel will have a value for only R or G or B.

Comment: How do you decide what becomes R, G or B? Luminosity?

Comment: xenoid - I manually select the areas of interest, probably using a Path; depends what works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is keep the value of the R (or G or B) channel in the selection, while setting the other two components to 0:

- Create a layer group above your image layer
- Add a transparent layer in the group, name it "Green", bucket-fill with green
- Add a transparent layer in the group, above "Green", name it "Red+Blue"
- Set the group to "Multiply" mode. You should see your image in green.
- To add red/blue, make a selection, make sure "Red+Blue" is the active layer, and bucket fill the selection with Red or Blue.

[image: Example]

#### Notes

- With some selection tools, (path, ellipse...) you may have to use `Select>Sharpen` before the bucket-fill to make sure that there are no partially selected pixels
- To see the original image when making selections, just make the group invisible.
- You can also use two separate layers for Red and Blue (both above the Green one, in the layer group)
- If what you want is just areas of #FF0000 and #0000FF over a #00FF00 background, then just hide the initial image layer when exporting.

Comment: xenoid - you're my "star" of the day. I can reproduce your result (there are some less obvious facilities that I would never have found). Even better, I don't have to constrain my work to the 3 primary colours - I can highlight 256*256*256 different selections as long as I note the colour balance for post-processing. Thanks again